# How to control entity ownership in JHipster dialogs?

Tags: jhipster

Let’s say that we have an entity Profile of this type:

```
relationship ManyToOne {
    Profile{user(id) required} to User{profile}
}
```

That Profile has you bio in a property, for example, and only you should be able to update or delete it, but everybody should see it.

I have seen that there is a way to checkout, at the EntityResource.java level, if the user is an Admin or User and let him take any of the CRUD actions, but I would like to know if there is a way to check if the current user is the user that has created that Entity, so only owner of the entities and Admins can Update or Delete their own entities.

```
    if (!SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ENTITY_NAME, "Not-authorized", "You need to be logged in to perform this action")).body(null);
    }
```

SecurityUtils has this methods:

- isAuthenticated
- isCurrentUserInRole
- getCurrentUserLogin

I guess that if I can get the User by using the  Profile – User relationship, I can compare it with the Profile.User.Login, but I only have the Profile.User.Id and I do not see how to get the  Profile.User.Login

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried spring security expression language ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize

Comment: Does your entity use DTOs or service classes?

Comment: Thanks Gaël. I wish I could see an example. I do not know how. Thanks Jon, I would use whatever is easier (DTOs, service classes or the best practice, you name it).